# Uicollection View ios 6 and ios7 issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i using tabbar in a view when i set tabbar height 1000 then collection view also increase its size and when i set tabbar hiegt 568 it disappear.i dont know how to resolve it

also there is and status bar issue when i run application in ios6.if my question is very complex for understanding then just ping me.so i can give whole information regarding this issue.

Here is my code.

```
//In View Controller:

     - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tabbar_obj = [[mytabbar alloc] initWithNibName:@"mytabbar" bundle:nil];

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ipad ");
    }
    else
    {

        NSLog(@"Iphone %f ",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
        if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
        {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
            tabbar_obj.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
            //this is iphone 5 xib

           // tabbar_obj.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);

        } else //if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
        {

            tabbar_obj.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
            // this is iphone 4 xib
        }
    }
        else if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.1"))
        {
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
              //  tabbar_obj.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 568);
                //this is iphone 5 xib
                [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 568)];
                tabbar_obj.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);

            } else //if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 460)
            {
                [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
                tabbar_obj.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320,568);
                // this is iphone 4 xib
            }

        }
    [self.view addSubview:tabbar_obj.view];
    appdel.mytabbar_obj = tabbar_obj;
    }
}
```

[image: When tabbar height is 568]
[image: when tabbar height is 1000]

Comment: "i set tabbar height 1000 then collection view also increase its size and when i set tabbar hiegt 568 it disappear" What does this mean ???

Comment: @IronManGill i solved issue thanks for support but still facing an issue that is images is not shown in collection view i set frame of 600